# React sends Form input to backend everytime i make a change to input field

Tags: reactjs, post, input, axios

> I have this function that sends a post request to my express backend

```
function postFood (foodName, foodType, foodDescription){
  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/food", {
  foodName: foodName,
  foodType: foodType,
   foodDescription: foodDescription,
 }).then(() => {
   console.log("food created successfully" + foodName, foodType, foodDescription);
 });
};
```

> This is my React component that takes the user input(foodName, foodType, foodDescription) and
> stores them in states and should send them to my backend *ONLY* when pressing the submit button
> but it sends the information everytime i make a change to any of the input fields

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import postFood from "./Services/createFood";

 function NewFood({ closeFoodForm }) {

 const [foodName, setfoodName] = useState("");
 const [foodType, setfoodType] = useState("Hamburger");
 const [foodDescription, setfoodDescription] = useState("");


   // this function gets called everytime i make a change to the input fields.
  postFood(foodName, foodType, foodDescription);

 return (
  <div className="CreateNewFood">
   <form id="foodForm" >
   
    <label>Name</label>
    <input
      onChange={e => {
        setfoodName(e.target.value);
      }}
      id="inputFoodName"
      name="foodName"
    ></input>

   
    <select id="inputFoodType" name="foodType"
      onChange={e => setfoodType(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="hamburger">Hamburger</option>
      <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
      <option value="kebab">Kebab</option>
    </select>

    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea
      onChange={e => {
        setfoodDescription(e.target.value);
      }}
      id="inputFoodDescription"
      placeholder="big hamburger with double patties "
      name="foodDescription"
    ></textarea>
     
    //when i press this button i would like to submit the form
    <button type="Submit" value="Submit"  id="submitButton" onClick={postFood}>
      Create
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `postFood` on every rerender. Remove this:

```js
// this function gets called everytime i make a change to the input fields.
postFood(foodName, foodType, foodDescription);
```

And edit the `<button />` element like so:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" onClick={() => postFood(foodName, foodType, foodDescription)}>
   Create
</button>
```

Note: you should probably not use `onClick`, instead use `onSubmit` on the `<form />` element and remove `onClick` from the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
<button type="Submit" value="Submit"  id="submitButton" onClick={() => postFood(foodName, foodType, foodDescription)}>
          Create
</button>
```

And remove the line

```
postFood(foodName, foodType, foodDescription);
```

Otherwise every change on the state is going to trigger the function